# Java/Spring: Get MessageSource file path from other Spring applications

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classpath

I am trying to write a MessageSourceFileLocator in my utility project.

The  utility project contains some utility classes, which are packed in a JAR file. The JAR file is added to any other Spring application I have.

How is it possible to locate the MessageSource file in another Spring application. I can search by file name, because it is always the same for the MessageSource.

I need to know the effective file location/path.

Comment: Just explode the jar and go to the package path you used to import the class.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more in detail?